# Pandas groupby sum - group on two variables, sum all other numeric variables and change the original dataframe

Tags: pandas-groupby

As mentioned above, I'd like to group by two variables ('town_code', 'ballot'), sum the total of all numeric variables (number of votes for political parties) in those groups, and actually change the original dataframe (called "results", to be grouped). Note that the dataframe contains also a non-numeric column - which is names. Names are identical inside each group, so I just need to make sure it stays after the process.

example:
this is what I have:
[image]

and this is what I need:
[image]

In the meanwhile I've managed to stay only with the numeric variables while losing the non-numeric and the groupby variables, using this line of code:

```
results = results.groupby(['town_code','ballot']).sum()
```

Comment: can  you elaborate with example your language is not too much clear

Comment: I did my best now, adding two tables as photos.

Answer (score 0):

I think below code fullfill your required  solution

```
import pandas as pd
town_code=[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4,4]
ballot=[1,2,3,3,1,2,2,1,2,1,2]   
town_name=['townsville','townsville','townsville','townsville','citysville','citysville'
             ,'citysville','villagesville','villageville','policeville','policeville']
party_a=[14,11,14,10,8,7,16,9,13,12,9]
party_b=[13,17,9,11,9,15,19,21,15,8,11]


df=pd.DataFrame({'town_code':town_code,'ballot':ballot,'town_name':town_name,
                                                'party_a':party_a,'party_b':party_b})

import numpy as np
pd.pivot_table(df,values=['party_a','party_b'],
                              index=['town_code','ballot','town_name'],aggfunc=np.sum)
```

[image]

Comment: Running this I get an error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "..........", line 71, in <module>
    results.pivot_table(results, values=['party_a','party_b'], index=['town_code', 'ballot', 'town_name'], aggfunc=np.sum)
TypeError: pivot_table() got multiple values for argument 'values'